# native languages which has good GUI

Tags: user-interface, native

Can you people list the native languages?

As far as I know its C,C++ and even VC++.
and then Delphi has an option to use both native or .net.

Anymore native languages which suports a nice GUI ?

C,C++ can do my work but is there any language which also suports vectors like WPF or Microsoft Expression Blend etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, Delphi provides a good GUI frameworks with native compilation.
Ex: http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/VCL/ (and they continue to support VCL, with a new "Metro style" Controls)

I don't know if you concider GTK as "nice GUI" (you can describe your UI in XML with [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/), pretty much as WPF and XAML). 
Gnome provides a "high level" language called [Vala](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/GTKSample), close to C#, but which is native... well, in fact it generates C source code and then compile to native, but it's transparent to you, and you can use other native C libraries.